# Passing this object to xhr function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, object, this

I am trying to pass `this` object as parameter from ajax xhr to external function but it seems not working. Below is my code.

```
  $(document).on("click", "#imgform_submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var thiss = $(this);          //  $(this)  object
    var href = window.location.href;
    var form_id = href.substr(href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    var formData = new FormData($("form#imgform")[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url + "index.php/init/add_img/" + form_id,
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        xhr: function () {  // custom xhr
            var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if (myXhr.upload) { // Check if upload property exists
                myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', progressHandler(thiss), false);// For handling the progress of the upload
            }
            return myXhr;
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if(data == "true"){
                 $("#file_upload_container").html("<div class='msg'>File Successfully Uploaded</div>");
             }

        },
        complete: function () { //     
        }

    });

});
```

*progressHandler*

```
 function progressHandler(e, thiss) {
    $(thiss).hide();     //this line is not working.
    var progress = document.getElementById('progress');
    //  var status = document.getElementById('status');
    var percent = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
    percent = Math.round(percent);
    progress.style.width = Math.round(percent) + '%';
    //  status.innerHTML = percent + '% completed.';
}
```

Above I am passing `this` as parameter to function `progressHandler` and trying to access it. I didn't worked. Help me.

*Edited*

I forgot to mention one thing that. `#imgform_submit` button is triggered from jquery code as:

```
$(document).on("click", ".uploadimg", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var filebrowser = $(this).prev().prev(".uploadContainer").children("#file_browser");
    var inputfile = filebrowser.children('.upload');
    if (inputfile.val() == '') {
        alert("Please select file before uploading.");
    } else {
        $("#imgform").prepend(filebrowser);
        $("#imgform_submit").trigger("click");
    }
});
```

Now I want to pass `this` object of `.uploadimg` button to `#imgform_submit` function and similarly to `progressHanlder` function. Finally, `progressHanlder` should be able to use `this` object of `.uploadimg`. I tried.

```
 $(document).on("click", ".uploadimg", function (e) {
   //some code
 $("#imgform_submit").trigger("click", $(this));
```

And

```
 $(document).on("click", "#imgform_submit", function (e, thiss) {
     $(thiss).hide();   // .uploadimg button is hidden here. works well.
     myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', progressHandler(thiss), false);  //passing thiss object of .uploadimg to progressHandler 
 });

 function progressHandler(e, thiss) {
    $(thiss).hide();    //it didnot worked here.
 })
```

Above I am writing in shortcut. `.uploadimg` `this` object is not working in `progressHandler` function now. How to overcome this situation.

Comment: you can use **JSON.stringify($(form_data).serialize())**

Answer (score 0):

Appear to be calling `progressHandler` function at

```
myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', progressHandler(thiss), false)
```

?

Try utilizing `.bind()`

```
myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', progressHandler.bind(e.target), false)
```

at `progressHandler` remove `thiss` as parameter , use `$(this)` as selector

```
function progressHandler(e) {
    $(this).hide();     //this line is not working.
    var progress = document.getElementById('progress');
    //  var status = document.getElementById('status');
    var percent = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
    percent = Math.round(percent);
    progress.style.width = Math.round(percent) + '%';
    //  status.innerHTML = percent + '% completed.';
}
```

Comment: I am trying to bind clicked button `#imgform_submit` object to progressHandler function. But your code seems to bind another `this` object.

Comment: @user254153 At `click` event `e.target` should be `#imgform_submit` : `this` ; try `$(document).on("click", "#imgform_submit", function (e) {console.log(e.target)})` , at `progressHandler` `function progressHandler(e) {console.log(this)}` ; see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: I tried that but it didn't worked. `$(this).hide()` should hide the clicked button in `progressHandler` function. But clicked button is not hidden.

Comment: @user254153 Can create jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ? What does `console.log(this)` return within `progressHandler` ?

Comment: It return the button element that was clicked. I think your code is correct. I misunderstood it. Actually I am triggering the `#imgform_submit` button from jquery code when other button is clicked. Now, How can I pass `this` object to trigger function. I will edit my question. thanks for help.

Comment: THank you for the fiddle. It works for me when there is single progress bar. But I am working in multiple progress bar for multiple image. So I need to pass an object and let know that progress bar is of specific image.

Comment: @user254153 _"It works for me when there is single progress bar. But I am working in multiple progress bar for multiple image. So I need to pass an object and let know that progress bar is of specific image. "_ ? Utilize `.bind()` , same process as at solution above, jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Loaf681w . Note, `.trigger()` accepts array `[]` as second argument `$("#imgform_submit").trigger("click", [$(this)])` ; though `$("#imgform_submit").trigger("click")` should call attached handler of `click` delegated to `"#imgform_submit"` selector , where `this` should be set to `"#imgform_submit"`

Answer (score 0):

You problem is, that you do not pass the method `progressHandler` to the event listener. What you are doing is executing the method with yoiur `this` object as first parameter and using the return value of the execution (which is `undefined`) as the callback of the event listener.

What you can use to solve this problem is an anonymous function which executes the function you need like you need:

```
myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (e) {
    progressHandler.call(thiss, e);
}, false);
```

So what you do is passing a function to the listener which executes your `progressHandler` while passing `thiss` as `this` object and `e` as the first parameter.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call